# Java Array Out of Bounds Exception from Properties

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, properties

I am trying to utilize a .properties file to get a list of strings and transform them into an array to be added with javassist later in my program. However, I keep getting an arrayoutofboundsexception 0 with the following data in properties:
modify.spells.in.

```
    void configure(Properties options)
    {
        String nameSpace;
        ArrayList<String> spellList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] tokens;

        for(String key : options.stringPropertyNames()) {
            if(key.startsWith("modify.spells.in.")) {
                nameSpace = key.substring(17);
                tokens = options.getProperty(key).split(",");
                for(String token : tokens) {
                    if(spellList.contains(nameSpace + "." + token)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    spellList.add(nameSpace + "." + token);
                }
            }
        }

        if(spellList.size() == 0) {
            itemSpells = new String[]{
                    "Fire1", "Fire2",  "Fire3", "Lit1", "Lit2", "Lit3", "Ice1", "Ice2",
                    "Ice3"
            };

            for(int i = 0; i < itemSpells.length; i++) {
                itemSpells[i] = "com.ragdoll.spells." + itemSpells[i];
            }
        } else {
            itemSpells = spellList.toArray(new String[0]);
        }
```

The properties file string is as follows:
modify.spells.in.com.ragdoll.spells=Fire3,Lit3,Ice3

The expression to edit the existing code is as follows:

I have a HookManager to add in interceptSpells(itemSpells);

```
    private void interceptSpells(String[] classes) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException
    {
        CtClass c;
        ClassPool cp = HookManager.getInstance().getClassPool();
        CtMethod m = null;

        // CAST - 

        for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            c = cp.get(classes[i]);
            m = c.getDeclaredMethods("doEffect")[0];
            m.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
                public void edit(MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException {
                    if (m.getMethodName().equals("addSpellEffect")) {
                        logger.info("Intercepting (1) " + classes[j]);
                        m.replace(
                              "$_ = $proceed($$);"
                            + "com.rev.spellmod.getInstance().addSpellEffectCaster($0, eff, performer); "
                        );
                    } else if(m.getMethodName().equals("improvePower")) {
                        logger.info("Intercepting (2) " + classes[j]);
                        m.replace(
                              "$_ = $proceed($$);"
                            + "com.rev.spellmod.getInstance().replaceSpellEffectCaster($0, eff, performer); "
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
```

I feel as though I have declared the namespace and am splitting the list correctly. If I add just one spell in the .properties file, it works. As soon as I add more than one it points back to the intercept code with the arrayoutofboundsexception. If I leave it blank, it also works with the pre-determined spells, but I was hoping to be able to modify the spells on the go rather the recompiling each time.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realized the doEffect was the issue. Some of the spells inherited doEffect from another class and so that was producing the ArrayOutOfBoundsException not the parsing of the string which was correct.